# Server, what do I need exactly?

Tags: java, android

when people talk about having a server that receives request ( say to update tickets in DB, or fetch tickets..etc), what kind of server are we talking here? Is it just a webserver (say from host gator) and couple of PHP scripts handling requests or are we talking about specific kind of server (different than web hosting server)?

My intention is to have an android app that sends a ticket to server and track status. Kind of like bug tracker.
Thank you

Comment: It could be anything from a fault-tolerant distributed cloud-based HA cluster to the Arduino stuck in my potted plant. What are you trying to find out?

Comment: @DaveNewton Why do you have an Arduino stuck in your potted plant?

Comment: @Jeffrey why do you *not*?!? ;-)

Comment: @Jeffrey Its screams for water sustain me.

Comment: @DaveNewton - so now you ALSO have an Arduino in your plant pot that screams "change my batteries" :-)

Comment: @StephenC No no, I'm quite good about taking care of the Arduino!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(to add to Jasons detailed answer about "what servers are")

Depending on your knowledge of running a server whether it be through an ssh connection to a shell or a control panel, I would suggest getting a very cheap low end server.

for example: ramhost.us offers low end servers with root access, or even cheaper solutions for shared servers where you have "limited" amounts of features like how many mysql databases if you want everything already setup and a basic control panel like host gator would give you.

Let's assume you were doing bug tracking:
Tho I have not looked into it myself. If you wanted a cool framework for handling bugs and tracking them instead of writing your own php scripts you could install

Mantis bug tracking: 
http://www.mantisbt.org/

and possibly hook into and create a simple php script using a public/private key encryption to create new bug reports

source: I'm a client of ramhost and have used their servers to run simialar setups and hooked into a "phpbb3" forum framework through a custom php script with public private key encryption to create user accounts externally

Comment: Thank you for the full answer and I like the suggestions you made  about different db. It is really not bugs system per say I am talking about (I just found the closest technical concept). It is tickets systems I am looking into :)

Answer (score 2):

Well by "Server" people are talking about a stack of software (like Apache+PHP (web server) running on Linux with MySQL (Database server)) and hardware (physical server or virtual server) connected to a network.  These can all be on one box (what might be called a web server) or they could represent a capability of a larger computer that does a lot of other things (what might be a "local web server".  By "having" people for the most part mean being able to control and expect it to respond when requested.  They could achieve this control and expectation by paying a web hosting provider who agrees to keep a server running at a specified IP address or by buying a computer and loading it up with server software.

Comment: Thanks Jason, Although thats probably too technical of what I am looking for here. I needed bascially to know, if I am to look for server what to search for. Thats why  I mentioned hostgator. as I wanted to see if web host is different from DB server (in terms of companies provided). +1 for the nice information though

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you want to do. You could rent webserver and run some scripts there, or for example you could use your own computer to run the DB and scripts.

You could make your own server, if you have an old computer that could be turned on 24/7!